# How to implement a filter from another stream using RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

So I have two steam like this :

```
--1--2--3--4--5--6-|
-----A-----B-------|
```

My goal will be to have a stream like this

```
--1----3------5--6-|
```

I have tried using operator like takeUntil or skipUntil but I haven't been able to produce something that work. Can you give me some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there is the problem of coincidence between 2 and A, you have to define a window where the second stream can prevent the first one's value to be emitted. For example, this will wait 1 milliseconds per item (2.x):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.*;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.TestScheduler;

public class Coincidence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestScheduler sch = new TestScheduler();

        Flowable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, sch)
        .onBackpressureBuffer()
        .compose(coincide(Flowable.interval(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, sch), sch))
        .take(7)
        .subscribe(v -> 
            System.out.printf("%d - %d%n", sch.now(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), v));

        sch.advanceTimeBy(1001, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    static <T, U> FlowableTransformer<T, T> coincide(
            Flowable<U> other, Scheduler scheduler) {
        return f -> {
            return other.publish(g -> {
                return f.flatMap(v -> {
                    return Flowable.just(v)
                            .delay(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
                            .takeUntil(g)
                    ;
                }, 1)
                .takeUntil(g.ignoreElements())
                ;
            });
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Do you think that my answer can be a valid option, if we assume a different semantic about the term "coincidence" (as I explained in the answer)?

Comment: Looks okay to me. My answer has a forward window and yours has a backwards window and total ordering of events. Both of us could be right and both of us could be wrong depending on the OP's expectations.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I think that it depends on what is the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that akarnokd gave the only possible solution, if you need to deal with "coincidence".

By the way, in most of the case probably you don't need the events to happen at the same time, or in a specific temporal window, but you just need to check if a certain event occur before the item is emitted. For example, your scenario could be adjusted like this:

```
--1-----2----3------4------5--6-|
-------A----------B-------------|
```

Which means that A (happening after 2), will prevent it to pass through. The same is true for 4 and B.

If this is the case I would solve it in as following: 
merging the two `Observables` and then using a scan for determine which item should be propagated downstream, and eventually filtering the result.

```
 Observable.merge(Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).map(integer -> new ValueObject(integer)),
        Observable.just("A", "B").map(string -> new BarrierObject(string)))
        .scan((myObject, myObject2) -> {
            if (myObject instanceof BarrierObject) {
                myObject2.setFilter();
            }

            return myObject2;
        })
        .filter(myObject -> (myObject instanceof ValueObject) && myObject.isValid())
        .map(myObject -> (Integer) myObject.getValue())
        .subscribe(integer -> Log.d("test", "value: " + String.valueOf(integer)));
```

Where `ValueObject` and `BarrierObject` extends the following class:

```
abstract class MyObject {
    boolean toBeFiltered;
    Object value;

    public void setFilter() {
        toBeFiltered = true;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return !toBeFiltered;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @akarnokd do you think it is a reasonable solution, with the pre-explained assumption?

Comment: In order to get response post your comment on his answer then he will get notification, i think.